# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

I am facing a peculiar problem with an asp.net 2.0 application(C# code behind) which has been running smoothly for last 3 years or so.The thing is that I have one custom object named "Horse" which becomes null at a particular line where I check for its nullability though there is seemingly no reason for its becoming null at this line.Interestingly when I spit the content of this object using Response.Write just before the line where I am getting the null reference exception, it shows the content of the "horse" object to the browser.

More interesting thing is that if I access the page from IE 6.0 and IE 7.0,I don't get the exception at all.But if I use IE 8.0,then I get this exception.

Can anyone please tell me reason and solution for this issue?
Thanks in advance!
Subrata

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you post the full stack of the error, and the actual code where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Browser differences should not impact server side objects in .NET. It could be a red herring. As Rex M suggested please post some code and the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

What Rex M and Nikhil say are very true.  However, have you tried clearing cookies/cache?

If the app is relying on a cookie and the browser storage has become overloaded then I've seen this happen before.